# The smallest disc which could contain 11 coins

Tags: mathematics, geometry

There are $11$ coins with $1$ unit radius and we are trying to put them inside a big disc with some radius. So

> What is the minimum radius of this disc?

- If this question was asked for $2$ coins, the answer would be obviously $2$ unit radius,
- If was asked for $3$ coins, the answer would be $1+\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\cong 2.16$ unit radius as shown below:

[image]

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_packing_in_a_circle

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is

> $1+\frac{1}{\sin\frac{\pi}{9}}\approx3.923$

which can be done like this (image courtesy of [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_packing_in_a_circle)):

> [image: solution]

but it is highly non-trivial to demonstrate that this is optimal. It was first proved by Hans Melissen in ["Densest packings of eleven congruent circles in a circle", *Geometriae Dedicata* 50(1) (1994), pp. 15–25](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01263647), by a proof sufficiently complex that I don't want to reproduce it here.

Comment: lol I had to idea there was such a paper -.-

Comment: When a seemingly simple geometry problem that the ancient Greeks could have understood isn't proven until the 90s, you know that it has to be complicated :D

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_packing_in_a_circle